# Как очистить cookie пользователя в Golang

Tags: golang

Я выдаю при авторизации пользователю Cookie

```
http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
    Name:  "user-cookie", 
    Value: token,  
    Path: "/",
})
```

Как можно их у него очистить?

Comment: Выдать куку с пустым значением и отрицательным временем жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно передать атрибут `Max-Age` < 0, что означает удаление cookie в данный момент времени.

```
c := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "storage",
    Value:    "",
    Path:     "/",
    MaxAge:   -1,
    HttpOnly: true,
}

http.SetCookie(rw, c)
```